# how to create a data.frame with nested column structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to create a data.frame with two columns, and each column contains multiple columns. (I need it to feed plsr in the pls package)

It's like the oliveoil data.

```
> oliveoil
   chemical.Acidity chemical.Peroxide chemical.K232 chemical.K270 chemical.DK sensory.yellow sensory.green
G1           0.7300           12.7000        1.9000        0.1390      0.0030           21.4          73.4
G2           0.1900           12.3000        1.6780        0.1160     -0.0040           23.4          66.3
G3           0.2600           10.3000        1.6290        0.1160     -0.0050           32.7          53.5
G4           0.6700           13.7000        1.7010        0.1680     -0.0020           30.2          58.3
G5           0.5200           11.2000        1.5390        0.1190     -0.0010           51.8          32.5
I1           0.2600           18.7000        2.1170        0.1420      0.0010           40.7          42.9
I2           0.2400           15.3000        1.8910        0.1160      0.0000           53.8          30.4
I3           0.3000           18.5000        1.9080        0.1250      0.0010           26.4          66.5
I4           0.3500           15.6000        1.8240        0.1040      0.0000           65.7          12.1
I5           0.1900           19.4000        2.2220        0.1580     -0.0030           45.0          31.9
S1           0.1500           10.5000        1.5220        0.1160     -0.0040           70.9          12.2
S2           0.1600            8.1400        1.5270        0.1063     -0.0020           73.5           9.7
S3           0.2700           12.5000        1.5550        0.0930     -0.0020           68.1          12.0
S4           0.1600           11.0000        1.5730        0.0940     -0.0030           67.6          13.9
S5           0.2400           10.8000        1.3310        0.0850     -0.0030           71.4          10.6
S6           0.3000           11.4000        1.4150        0.0930     -0.0040           71.4          10.0
   sensory.brown sensory.glossy sensory.transp sensory.syrup
G1          10.1           79.7           75.2          50.3
G2           9.8           77.8           68.7          51.7
G3           8.7           82.3           83.2          45.4
G4          12.2           81.1           77.1          47.8
G5           8.0           72.4           65.3          46.5
I1          20.1           67.7           63.5          52.2
I2          11.5           77.8           77.3          45.2
I3          14.2           78.7           74.6          51.8
I4          10.3           81.6           79.6          48.3
I5          28.4           75.7           72.9          52.8
S1          10.8           87.7           88.1          44.5
S2           8.3           89.9           89.7          42.3
S3          10.8           78.4           75.1          46.4
S4          11.9           84.6           83.8          48.5
S5          10.8           88.1           88.5          46.7
S6          11.4           89.5           88.5          47.2
```

And it is a data.frame with 2 columns:

```
> is.data.frame(oliveoil)
[1] TRUE

> dim(oliveoil)
[1] 16  2
```

I tried the following code:

```
x = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(1,3,4))
y = data.frame(c = c(3,4,5), d = c(5,4,2))

d = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

it returns:

```
> d
  x.a x.b y.c y.d
1   1   1   3   5
2   2   3   4   4
3   3   4   5   2
```

but I cannot call x with d$x

```
> d$x
NULL
```

what I expect is:

```
> d$x
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

I am expecting some arguments in the data.frame function make it work, something like:

```
d = data.frame(x = x, y = y, merge.columns = F)
```

But I cannot find any arguments doing this in the docs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames)

Comment: @camille unfortunately no. what i want is a dataframe, not a list

Comment: Hang on, I mean - `data.frame(x = I(as.matrix(x)), y = I(as.matrix(y)))` ?

Comment: @thelatemail. Yes, that works. Thanks a lot!. But as.matrix change the values in y to string. I will try if plsr works when I convert it to numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pls::plsr()` function does not require data to be set up exactly like `oliveoil`.  `plsr()` allows the response term to be a matrix, and `oliveoil` has a particular way of storing matrices, but you can supply any matrix to `plsr()`.

For example, this fits a model without error:

```
y <- matrix(rnorm(n), nrow = 10)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n), nrow = 10)

plsr(y ~ x)
# Partial least squares regression , fitted with the kernel algorithm.
# Call:
# plsr(formula = y ~ x)
```

Also, consider that the `yarn` dataset is also used in the [`pls` docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/vignettes/pls-manual.pdf), which just stores regular matrices in a data frame rather than the `I()` approach used by `oliveoil`.

For a bit more explanation:

The sub-components of `oliveoil` are not actually of class `data.frame`.
If you run `str(oliveoil)`, you'll see the `sensory` and `chemical` objects in `oliveoil` are cast as `AsIs` objects.  They're not technically data frame-classed objects, and in fact they were probably matrices with named rows and columns to begin with.

```
str(oliveoil)

'data.frame':   16 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ chemical: 'AsIs' num [1:16, 1:5] 0.73 0.19 0.26 0.67 0.52 0.26 0.24 0.3 0.35 0.19 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr  "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr  "Acidity" "Peroxide" "K232" "K270" ...
 $ sensory : 'AsIs' num [1:16, 1:6] 21.4 23.4 32.7 30.2 51.8 40.7 53.8 26.4 65.7 45 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr  "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr  "yellow" "green" "brown" "glossy" ...
```

The `AsIs` class means they were stored in `oliveoil` using the [`I()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/AsIs) function (I think "I" is for "Identity").  `I()` protects an object from being converted into something else during an operation, like storage into a data frame.

You can reproduce this with a simple example (although note that if you try and store two data frames in a data frame with `I()` you'll get an error):

```
n <- 100
matrix_a <- matrix(rnorm(n), nrow = 10)
matrix_b <- matrix(rnorm(n), nrow = 10)

df <- data.frame(a = I(matrix_a), b = I(matrix_b))

str(df)

'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: 'AsIs' num [1:10, 1:10] -0.817 -0.233 -1.987 0.523 -1.596 ...
 $ b: 'AsIs' num [1:10, 1:10] 1.9189 -0.7043 0.0624 0.0152 -0.5409 ...
```

And `df` now contains `matrix_a` as `$a` and `matrix_b` as `$b`:

```
df$a
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
 [1,] -0.8167554 -0.61629222  0.3673423  1.30882012  0.97618868 -0.53124825
 [2,] -0.2329451  0.08556506 -0.5839086  0.86298000  1.20452166  0.09825958
 [3,] -1.9873738 -0.93537922  0.1057309  0.63585036 -1.09604531  1.33080572
 [4,]  0.5227912  1.89505993  1.1184905  1.20683770 -0.02431886 -1.15878634
# ...
```

You could also just save `matrix_a` and `matrix_b` as matrices, directly:

```
# also works
df2 <- data.frame(a = matrix_a, b = matrix_b, foo = letters[1:10])
```

**TL;DR** - `plsr()` takes any matrix, but if you want your data stored in a data frame, create a matrix and save it into a data frame, with or without `I()`.